# jqPlot Graph "TypeError"

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, jqplot

In my Firebug, it is showing me:

```
TypeError: this[r]._ticks[0] is undefined
```

But in my JS Array, the items are well constructed. Should not be the data problem.

[image]

So, as i said it should not be the data problem. The mystery is:

- The problem is not consistent, just that **SOMETIME JUST GOT WHOLE BLANK**.
- I have multiple log ranges (e.g, Show 1 week, Show 1 day, Show 1 hour), then sometime some got BLANK like now and at the same time, graphs are OK in some time ranges. And next time, this range got OK and next range got problem. (With this same code, same data)
- I am super sure all my Array Rooms are filled with respective data inside. (I got no blank or corrupted array rooms)

I'm outta idea already :S
Please help.

Comment: It is hard to say anything without code example.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem this day, and resoled this by hard coding the second array value is number but not string type. You can do this simply in php code:  $output["1"]=**(double)**$var, then try to use json_encode to output the data.

Here is the difference example:
valid array format:

```
var data=[[['2014-01', 2],['2014-02',5.12],['2014-03',13.1],['2014-04',33.6],['2014-05',85.9],['2014-06',219.9],['2014-07',39.9],['2014-08',99.9]]];
```

invalid array format:

```
var data=[[["2014-02","1920.97"],["2014-03","2040.92"],["2014-04","1704.52"],["2014-05","1630.88"],["2014-06","207.43"]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parseFloat(var) or parseInt(var) before passing data to the graph.

Where var is your variable or value which you are passing to graph.